# separator using border doesn't work cause by padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

any solution for this? http://bootply.com/104711

this is my markup using bootstrap

```
<div class="status-wrap">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 straight-line">
        <span>Interview Invitation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <span>Invited 7 Jan 2014</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The separator isn't strenght to its length because I applied padding. I can remove the height since I want to apply background to the row.

Comment: The question is not clear

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate the height found in the css class ".status-wrap" to the css class 
".status-wrap .straight-line" :

```
.status-wrap,
.status-wrap .straight-line {
    height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: ignore the mistake, and it doesn't cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
.status-wrap div {
  padding-top: 8px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

http://bootply.com/104712

or you can use the following if you want to remove the height: 35px from status-wrap class

http://bootply.com/104714